# Socket connection to localhost is timing out

Tags: php, apache, sockets, firewall, portforwarding

So I'm trying to get a hosted website (let's call it online.com) to be able to grab some text files from my Apache local (WAMP).

However when I run the code online.com loads for a while then presents error 100 (timed out). I don't know why.

I'm using sockets to do this. I have whitelisted the ip for online.com on my PC's firewall. I've added the listening port to Apache server. I've done the port forwarding (although I'm not 100% sure if I've done that correctly).

The following is a more symbolic representation of the above.

**port forwarding**

```
online.com's IP = X, port = 80
local host's IP = (used ipconfig) IPV4 Address, port = Y
```

**Apache**

```
Listening on port Y
```

**White listed**

```
Added IP X
```

When I run the php script on online.com

```
if (!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Connect socket to remote server


**if (!socket_connect($sock, 'IP X', PORTY))**
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Connection established \n";
$message = "GET / PRCC /HTTP/1.1 \r\n\r\n";

// Send the message to the server

if (!socket_send($sock, $message, strlen($message) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Message send successfully \n";
$buf = "";

// Now receive reply from server

if (socket_recv($sock, $buf, 2045, MSG_WAITALL) === FALSE)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

// print the received message

echo $buf . "this is the buffer";
socket_close($sock);
```

The line `if(!socket_connect($sock , 'IP X' , PORT Y))` is the cause of the issue.

Any suggestions about what could be wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error message?  Is that die() returning a specific error after your connection fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using sockets? Just attempt a regular HTTP request to your home IP with `file_get_contents()`.

Example,

```
<?php

$text_file1 = file_get_contents("http://YOUR_IP:PORT/PRCC");
// so on..
```

Comment: I'll try that, thank you very much. Let you know how it goes

Comment: This solution was exactly what I needed. I just had to change some of the Apache settings and open the right ports but now I can access from my cell phone! I've accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I realize now that this is client side code.

The connect methods will usually sleep until an appropriate answer is sent from the server.  Do you witness the socket server program attempting to respond to this client?  One way to check that is to have the server side write a log entry representing each connection attempt.

If the code is just sitting there, and not providing errors, it may just be waiting as it is supposed to.

When drafting experimental code for client-server systems in sockets, it can help to check for errors at every juncture like:  connect, bind, send, receive, listen, accept and close.

Comment: I'm going to try Carey's solution before I move forward with anything else involving sockets